# Memory efficient way of producing a weighted edge list

Tags: pandas, numpy, networkx, cosine-similarity

I have a DataFrame of features, indexed by ID.

```
ID1, Red, Green, Blue
ID2, Yellow, Green, Orange
ID3, Gray, Green, Yellow
ID4, Yellow, Green, Blue
```

I am trying to produce an edge list with cosine similarity as weights without producing the adjacency matrix first.

I have plenty of compute time, but are memory constrained and the dataset is large.

Need this, excluding weights of 0:

```
ID1 ID2 Weight (cosine similarity)
01 02 0.33
01 03 0.25
01 04 0.75
```

(weighs only for illustration)

Here is how I solve this by an adjacency matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df = df.pivot_table(index = ('ID'), columns= 'color', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
matrix = df.as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
matrix = cosine_similarity(matrix)
```

Using combinations I am able to produce the list, but not sure how to apply cosine_similarity excluding zeros to prevent filling up the memory.

```
edge_list = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(df.index.tolist(), 2)), columns=['Source', 'Target'])
```

Appreciate inputs. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very straightforward `for loop` approach:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vect = CountVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(df.add(' ').sum(1))

data = []
for i1, i2 in combinations(df.index.tolist(), 2):
    data.append([i1, i2,
                 cosine_similarity(X[df.index.get_loc(i1)], 
                                   X[df.index.get_loc(i2)]).ravel()[0]])
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Source','Target','Weight'])
```

Results:

vectorized source DF:

```
In [280]: X
Out[280]:
<4x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [281]: X.A
Out[281]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

representing it as a sparse DF:

```
In [282]: pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=0)
Out[282]:
   blue  gray  green  orange  red  yellow
0     1     0      1       0    1       0
1     0     0      1       1    0       1
2     0     1      1       0    0       1
3     1     0      1       0    0       1
```

resulting DF:

```
In [283]: data
Out[283]:
  Source Target    Weight
0    ID1    ID2  0.333333
1    ID1    ID3  0.333333
2    ID1    ID4  0.666667
3    ID2    ID3  0.666667
4    ID2    ID4  0.666667
5    ID3    ID4  0.666667
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Using the X matrix and the DF, I set up a list of combinations. I use this to iterate and populate the data: `for i1, i2 in comb_list: data.append([i1, i2, cosine_similarity(X[df.index.get_loc(i1)], X[df.index.get_loc(i2)]).ravel()[0]])` I get the following error: `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Comment: Needed more brackets around the arguments inside the cosine similarity function. `for i1, i2 in comb_list: data.append([i1, i2, cosine_similarity([X[df.index.get_loc(i1)]], [X[df.index.get_loc(i2)]]).ravel()[0]])`. Still, it does not exclude the combinations where the cosine similarity is 0, so it is not a complete solution. Need to add an if statement before the append, but can not get it working with the list output from this: `if [i1, i2, cosine_similarity([X[df.index.get_loc(i1)]], [X[df.index.get_loc(i2)]]).ravel()[0]] > 0:` @MaxU